# Print end parameter with carriage return prints nothing

Tags: python

I followed a tutorial to build a countdown timer. It works fine, but if I add

```
print(timer, end="\r")
```

Then I don't get any output. Nothing prints out, it does if I remove or change the endline character. I would like this timer to print in the same line, not to jump to a newline or so.

Here is the full code:

```
import time


def countdown(time_secs):
    while time_secs:
        mins, secs = divmod(time_secs, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        time_secs -= 1

    print("Timer completed!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = input("Enter the time in seconds: ")

    countdown(int(t))
```

Edit: Seems like a thing from PyCharm, running the program in a terminal works just fine.

Comment: It might be helpful to specify which OS are you using (works for me on Windows 7)

Comment: Your code works on Linux.

Comment: And also say if you are doing this in an IDE, and if so which one. The terminal emulations of IDEs do not behave exactly the same as a system console (by design). What happens if you do `print(timer, end=":")`? [edit] your question to add the details.

Comment: I am working on Windows 10.0.19042. 
As I found out it might be an issue from the IDE (PyCharm), when I run the program in a terminal, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In line 8 change end="\r" to end=" ", it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I don't get any output. Nothing prints out

These are not the same thing. You actually do print out the value of `timer`, but then `print()` also prints out a `\r` character which erases that output. The end result is no output.

Instead, you should print the `\r` at the beginning of each line:

```
print('\r', timer)
```

This will overwrite the previous `timer` value in the output only when you print the next `timer` value rather than overwriting it immediately each time.